# "Open webview developer tools" not working in VS Code 1.56+?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VS Code extension that uses a [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). Previously I could inspect and debug my webview using the `Developer: Open webview developer tools` command, which would open a new window with the Webview developer tools.

In VS Code 1.56 however, this command no longer opens a new window. What's going on and how can I debug my webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code 1.56 updates the majority of webviews to use normal `<iframe>` elements instead of Electron's `<webview>` tag. This lets you use VS Code's standard, top-level developer tools ( which can be opened with the `Developer: Toggle developer tools` command) to debug and inspect your webviews:

[image: Inspecting a webview in VS Code's developer tools]

This has a few benefits over `Developer: Open webview developer tools`:

- You can inspect multiple webviews from the same developer tools instance
- The developer tools no longer close when the webview goes away
- Errors and console messages from webviews are clearly printed in the standard developer console

#### Caveat

In VS Code 1.56, Webviews that enable search (with `.enableFindWidget`) are still implemented using a `<webview>` tag, so you must still use the  `Developer: Open webview developer tools` command to debug and inspect them.

We plan on migrating all webviews to use iframes sometime after 1.56

Comment: Excellent news Matt.